# Flutter how pass additional argument to Function(BuildContext) callback

Tags: flutter

I have a class with a callback function

```
 class MyText {
  final String text;
  final List<String> variants;
  final int id;
  final TextStyle style;
  final void Function(BuildContext) callback; 
  final bool isWidgetSpan;
  final String Answer;

  MyText({
    this.text,
    this.variants,
    this.style,
    this.callback,
    this.isWidgetSpan,
    this.id,
    this.Answer
  });
}
```

I need to pass to it `final void Function(BuildContext) callback;` not only the context, but also additional parameters, for example int and String. If i do so

```
 final void Function(BuildContext, int , String) callback;
```

The compiler agrees, but then
The argument type 'Null Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(BuildContext, int, String)'.

```
    var t = new MyText(
    isWidgetSpan: false,
    
   //Error pass callback
    callback: (context) {
      _showMyDialog(context, 100, "EXAMPLE" );
    },

    text: "${element.Name} ",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      fontSize: 20,
    ));



Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context, int id, String text) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          //title: Text(''),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: Text(
                      "A",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: Text(
                      "B",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need `(context, i, s) { ...`, not `(context) { ...`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own typedef to create your own callback function and used as type for your parameter in Text as I mentioned in step 2.

Step 1:

```
typedef MyDialogueCallback = void Function(
    BuildContext context, int index, String data);
```

Step 2:

```
class MyText {
  final String text;
  final List<String> variants;
  final int id;
  final TextStyle style;
  final MyDialogueCallback callback;
  final bool isWidgetSpan;
  final String Answer;

  MyText({
    this.text,
    this.variants,
    this.style,
    this.callback,
    this.isWidgetSpan,
    this.id,
    this.Answer
  });
}
```

Step 3:

```
var t = new MyText(
isWidgetSpan: false,
callback: (context, index, data) {
  _showMyDialog(context, 100, "EXAMPLE" );
},

text: "${element.Name} ",
style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.grey,
  fontSize: 20,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `callback` does not accept an integer and a string.

```
callback: (context, anInt, aString) { 
  _showMyDialog(context, 100, "EXAMPLE" );
},
```